# Spring Security Java Config no ContextLoaderListener registered

Tags: java, spring, security, config

Well, I just got this problem after configured my SecurityInitializer...

Basically, everything was working fine, but my SecurityContextHolder.getContext() was returning null after authentication.

I'm authenticating the user with the code below:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getAuthorities().get(0).getAuthority()));
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

So I decided to configure my SecurityInitializer to solve this problem like this:

```
@Order(2)
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

Ok, after that I'm facing another problem, now with ContextLoaderListener, which I didn't have before.

I'll put the rest of my configuration here...

```
@Order(1)
public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(2000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired private MongoUserDetailService userDetailService; 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/me*", "/user*").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService);
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.pub")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

So I have a few questions...

- Does the AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter take care of that for me?
- Why after configure the Security Initializer it stop working?
- and finally, I don't even know if my ContextSecurityHolder() is working lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the answer...

I followed this link:
[spring security java config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/quickstart.md)

After configure the RootConfig.class works fine!